# Moving cloud SQL between regions in Google cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

SQL vm is indicating that it's located in west-europe3, yet the ip and latency are reading from the US (34.106.10.9)

Navigated to SQL in google cloud, to find out that it's actually in the USA. Tried moving that SQL instance following guides to move an instance, but it's seems that there's a difference between a VM and a SQL instance. The method to move a VM doesn't work for SQL instance.

Any ideas?

Comment: The address for Google IP addresses is where the address is `registered` (company mailing address) and not the physical location where the IP is deployed.

Answer (score 3):

You can move your Cloud SQL database from a region to another one by using the [multi region replicas feature](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/cross-region-replicas).

Create a replicas in the US, wait the end of the synchronization, stop your master node in Europe and grant the US replica as master.

Of course the IP won't be the same, but your database migration is done.